# Cygwin installation message

Tags: cygwin

I want to ask about this error? The error states :

> This is the first time you've installed Cygwin 1.7.x. Please be
>   advised that this is a major release. If you have not done so already,
>   please check out the documentation at http://cygwin.com/ to see how
>   the upgrade could potentially affect any existing Cygwin instalation.

Comment: Why do you assume this is an error message? The posted message does not contain the word error at all? Please read and try to understand the messages yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that what you have experience is not an error but a warning instead. This is just saying that it is your first time installing the application. I have found this helpful thread to assist you further : http://www.techyv.com/questions/error-installation-messege-unix-windows